# How to get rid of "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod" ? I tried updating cocoapod and pod repo

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

In my react-native project, I want to updated all my dependencies , so I run the following commands:

1.To update to a new major version of all the packages, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

2. upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file :

   `ncu -u`
3. run the update:

   `npm update`

I checked `package.json` and `package-lock.jso`n, dependencies have been updated to latest version.

Then, I `cd` to `ios/` folder, and run `pod install`, however I get the following error:
[image]

Yes I see that in the error message it suggests run `pod repo update`, I did it:

[image]

I also run `sudo gem install cocoapods`, and tried again `pod install` but I still get the same error.

My React-Native version is 0.63.3

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'MyApp' do
  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'MyApp-tvOS' do
  # Pods for MyApp-tvOS

  target 'MyApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

How to get rid of the error?

(I also checked Xcode command-line-tool:
[image]
)

Comment: Did you check your XCode's command-line tool?

Comment: No, I don't understand, could you please be more specific, where/how/what to check for XCode's command-line tool?

Comment: Open your XCode, press command+, (preferences), select Location Tab. There is command-line tool.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update. So, I checked, then what to do with that? Do you mean the command line tool is having out dated version?

Comment: Can you provide us what is inside in your Podfile?

Comment: And which version of RN are you using?

Comment: Please see my updates again.

Comment: Try to replace pod **'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"** to **pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"**

Comment: Tried, now `pod install` yields a new error complaining another pod ```[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Folly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)

  In Podfile:
    Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)

    React-RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration`) was resolved to 0.63.3, which depends on
      Folly (= 2020.01.13.00)```

Comment: Delete Podfile.lock and try again

Comment: Is it safe to delete Podfile.lock? I mean is it so that `pod install` will re-genreate the Podfile.lock?

Comment: Yes. It'll be created again

Comment: Can we move to chat. I did that, now a new output, I would like to show you but it is too long for pasting here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225199/discussion-between-leem-fin-and-j-doe).

Comment: Did you get a chance to try what I said?

Answer (score 5):

For xcode 13 and react-native 0.66, the only solution that worked for me is:

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
 rm -rf node_modules/
 rm -rf package-lock.json 
 cd ios && pod deintegrate
 cd .. && rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock 
 npm install
 npm audit fix
 react-native link
 cd ios && pod install
 cd .. && react-native run-ios
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28408

Answer (score 2):

Try `pod install --repo-update`. This will update the out of date repos, then install pods.. worked for me!